# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not File

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, discord.py, typeerror

```
async def transcript(self, ctx):
    """Creates a transcript for the channel the command is entered in
    """
    if ctx.channel.category.name in self.bot.ticket_categories:
        transcript = await chat_exporter.export(ctx.channel)

        if transcript is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(text="Transcript creation failed!",
                                  color=0xDE3163)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        transcript_file = discord.File(io.BytesIO(),
                                       filename=f"transcript-{ctx.channel.name}.html")

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Transcript creation successful!",
                              color=0x00A86B)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(transcript_file, f"transcript-{ctx.channel.name}.html"))
```

I've made a python discord bot that prints the transcript of a given channel. However, when the command is run, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\amogh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amogh\Documents\GitHub\MiscBot\cogs\tickets.py", line 1613, in transcript
    await ctx.send(file=transcript_file)
  File "C:\Users\amogh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord_components\dpy_overrides.py", line 371, in send_override
    return await send(channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amogh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord_components\dpy_overrides.py", line 306, in send
    data = await state.http.send_files(
  File "C:\Users\amogh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 187, in request
    for params in form:
TypeError: 'FormData' object is not iterable
```

Comment: you need to read it
self.fp = open(fp, 'rb').read()

Comment: That's the discord.py module.

Comment: yah i have realised it

Answer (score 1):

`transcript_file` is already a `discord.File`, what's the purpose of wrapping it with another `discord.File`? You just need to send the `transcript_file` variable.

```py
await ctx.send(file=transcript_file)
```

Comment: Tried that, it returned a new error. I've updated my code and the error. Please take a look at it.